# storing output of ls command consisting of files with spaces in their names

Tags: linux, bash, filenames, ls

I want to store output of ls command in my bash script in a variable and use each file name in a loop, but for example one file in the directory has name "Hello world", when I do `variable=$(ls)` "Hello" and "world" end up as two separate entries, and when I try to do

```
for i in $variable
do
  mv $i ~
done
```

it shows error that files "Hello" and "world" doesn't exist.
Is there any way I can access all files in current directory and run some command even if the files have space(s) in their names.

Answer (score 2):

Say it with me: [**don't parse the output of `ls`!**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) For more information, see [this post on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/45600).

A better way of doing this is:

```
for i in *
do
    mv -- "$i" ~
done
```

or simply

```
mv -- * ~
```

Comment: @mklement0 Whoops, right, not sure how I missed that considering the question was specifically about filenames with spaces :) Edited.

Comment: This works if one wants to run commands on files in present directory, but I have to list all files in one directory and compare the file names with some text files....... so storing in a list might become necessary and  the directory might not be current directory as well. Also if I try s=("Hello world") it takes each word as a separate entries . How to store a sentence in a list an a single entry?

Comment: This will _still_ fail if you hava a file name starting with `-`. use `mv -- * ~`

Answer (score 2):

If you must, `dirfiles=(/path/of/interest/*)`.

And accept the admonition against parsing the output of `ls`!

I understand you are new to this and I'd like to help. But it isn't easy for me (us?) to provide you with an answer that would be of much help to you by the way you've stated your question.

Based on what I hear so far, you don't seem to have a basic understanding on how parameter expansions work in the shell. The following two links will be useful to you:
[Matching Pathnames](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073), [Parameters](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters?highlight=(parameter)%7C(substitution))

Now, if your task at hand is to operate on files meeting certain criteria then `find(1)` will likely to do the job.